# img:focus doesn't stay focus in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, focus

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLv32.png)

I want to make the image stay clicked.

I am using two images for each icon. one is when is not clicked. another is when is clicked. hover is working fine. but focus is not working at all.

i don't see any errors or mistakes. help me please!

this is body

```css
body{
 width:350px;
}

img {
  float:left;
  width:60px;
  height:50px;
}

#hardy{
  float:right;
}

.category{
  position: fixed;
  padding: 2em;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color:white; /*Grey*/
  padding:13px;
  height:57px;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

 
.img-top {
  display:none;
  z-index:99;
}


#restaurant:hover .img-top{
  display: inline;
}

#restaurant:hover .img-bottom{
  display:none;
}

#restaurant.img-top:focus {
  display: inline;
}
#restaurant.img-bottom:focus {
  display: none;
} 

#hotel:hover .img-top{
  display: inline;
}

#hotel:hover .img-bottom{
  display:none;
}

#pub:hover .img-top{
  display: inline;
}

#pub:hover .img-bottom{
  display:none;
}

#park:hover .img-top{
  display: inline;
}

#park:hover .img-bottom{
  display:none;
}

#tourism:hover .img-top{
  display: inline;
}

#tourism:hover .img-bottom{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="listView">
  <div class="category">
    <span id="restaurant">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/restaurant_list_icon.png" alt="restaurant" title="restaurant" class="img-bottom">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/restaurant_list_selected_icon.png" alt="restaurant" title="restaurant" class="img-top">
    </span>
    <span id="hotel">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/hotel_list_icon.png" alt="hotel" title="hotel" class="img-bottom">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/hotel_list_selected_icon.png" alt="hotel" title="hotel" class="img-top">
    </span>
    <span id="pub">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/pub_list_icon.png" alt="pub" title="pub" class="img-bottom">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/pub_list_selected_icon.png" alt="pub" title="pub" class="img-top">
    </span>
    <span id="tourism">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/tourism_list_icon.png" alt="tourism" title="tourism" class="img-bottom">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/tourism_list_selected_icon.png" alt="tourism" title="tourism" class="img-top">
    </span>
    <span id="park">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/park_list_icon.png" alt="park" title="park" class="img-bottom">
      <img src="./resources/icons/category/park_list_selected_icon.png" alt="park" title="park" class="img-top">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

it doesn't seem like focus is working. 
only hover is working. I've looked for the answer through googld but can't find.

can anyone have the answer why focus is not working? thank you!!!

Comment: snippet please.. we cant recreate this issue with so many external files (images)

Comment: Don't really understand what are you trying to do.
Are you trying to hide images on click?

Comment: your code is `#restaurant.img-top:focus` so it finds the element with an id of `restaurant` and also has a class of `img-top`.. So try to add space between `restaurant` and `img-top` something like `#restaurant .img-top:focus`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use javascript instead. Here's a sample implementation for you. I've used text instead of image since I don't have images here, just replace those with your images.

HTML code should be like this

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="" class="clickme" id="item1">Item 1 <!--add your original image here--></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="clickme" id="item2">Item 2 <!--add your original image here--> </a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.selected#item1{color:#f00; /*you can use background: url(yourimagepath); here instead of color */}
.selected#item2{color:#0f0; /*you can use background: url(yourimagepath); here instead of color */}
```

JS

```
$('.clickme').on('click',function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();

  $('.clickme').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected'); 
});
```

Here's a [working sample in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfHZV/1853/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Style You Added

```
#restaurant.img-top:focus {
display: inline;
}
#restaurant.img-bottom:focus {
display: none;
}
```

Current Style is

```
#restaurant .img-top:focus {
   display: inline;
}
#restaurant .img-bottom:focus {
    display: none;
}
```

#restaurant ids main Div and .img-bottom is sub img tag

Answer (score 0):

**Hover and Click**

Well the focus pseudo class wont work, because the hover pseudo class changes the state of the element when the cursor hovers away.

So in order to achieve this task we can create a custom class ( **selected** in the example below -- run the snippet )  using jquery and add or remove it on click events.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <title>peedikayil</title>
 <style>
  img{ width:200px; overflow:hidden; }
  .clickme:hover #item1{display: inline;}
  .clickme:hover #item2{display: none;}
  .clickme #item1{display:none;}
  .clickme #item2{display:inline;}
  .selected #item1{display:inline;}
  .selected #item2{display:none;}
   
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="" class="clickme">

  <span id="item1">
   <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/7/7/f/1268838238959637666link-zelda_red_mini-hi.png" alt="restaurant" >
  </span>

  <span  id="item2">
   <img src="https://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/0/5128/318633-zww_link11.jpg" alt="restaurant" >
  </span>
    
 </a>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var clicked = false;
    
    $('.clickme').on('click',function(e){ 
   
   e.preventDefault();
     
   this.clicked = !(this.clicked);
    
   if(this.clicked){ 
     $('.clickme').addClass('selected');
     }else{
     $('.clickme').removeClass('selected');
     }
        
   });

  });

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you a lot! it works nicely with your code. :-)